# How to make model from two requests Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

How to make model to post Json made from two Json files?

I make first request and get this Json

```
{
  "id": 123123,
  "materials" : {      
        "meta" : {
          "href" : "https://products-link.com/materials",          
          "size" : 1,        
      },
  }
}
```

Then using link "href" : "https://products-link.com/materials" from first Json i'm making second request and get second Json

```
{
  "name": "assembling",
  "product" : "product name"
}
```

Then i need to replace data in "materials" in first Json with second Json and get this

```
{
  "id": 123123,
  "materials" : {      
       "name": "assembling",
       "product" : "product name"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello ,multi-way  to create JSON to dart model**

1: Using this `https://jsontodart.com/`  converter,  this converter converts JSON to dart model file with the class

2: Using this package  `https://pub.dev/packages/json_to_model`

Thank you

Comment: this doesn't answer OP's question !!